Datatables and yadcf Filter client side doesn't work when we have a column with checkboxes
When i have a dummy column created to host the checkboxes, the filter seems to take the wrong column as an index and therefore also the wrong value to compare, so the range number filter doesn't work.
fiddles: /1fmwoq73/9/
im' using Datatables 1.10.11 and yadcf 0.9.4, the table is client-side, for the checkbox i use the select plugin of datatables.
How can i resolve this? Did i do something wrong? (i'm new to the use of these libraries.)
Thanks.

Resolved using the "column_number_data" property to specify the real column.
yadcf.init(t, [
  {
    column_number: 1, filter_type: "text"
},
{
    column_number: 5, filter_type: "range_number", filter_delay: 500, filter_reset_button_text: false, column_number_data: "4" 
},]);

